# Streaming version for Rust (nom 7) multiline parser

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to learn NOM, but I'm also new in Rust.

I have a text file with words on each line.
I want to split it to 2 files: valid ASCII (without control codes) and everything else.

```
extern crate nom;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>  {
    let file = File::open("/words.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines().filter_map(|result| result.ok()) {
        parse(line);
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn parse(line: String) {
    for c in line.chars() {
        if c.is_ascii_control() | !c.is_ascii() {
            println!("C> {}", line);
            return;
        }
    }
    if line.len() > 0 {
        println!("A{}> {}", line.len(), line);
    }
}
```

But input file is too large for in-memory processing and I should use Streaming functionality, like [this](https://github.com/rust-bakery/generator_nom/blob/master/src/main.rs).

How to modify this code to combine streaming buffer with limited capacity (1000 chars) and [line_ending](https://docs.rs/nom/7.0.0/nom/character/streaming/fn.line_ending.html) check?

Comment: Your current code only stores one line at a time in memory, so unless your input contains exceedingly long lines, you should be fine.

Comment: Just tested, you are right. Then what is the difference with streaming version?